# What is the best way to protect the Flask app python source code from been copied?

Tags: python, flask, cloud

I would like to know what is the best way to protect python source code of Flask app from been copied after it is deployed to the cloud provider.

My understanding of the process is as follows:

***- once app is in the cloud,  support staff for cloud infrastructure  could access and copy the source code of the app.***

Questions:

1. Is my understanding correct?
2. if Yes an answer to the first question,is anything could be done to limit access to source code by support  staff?

The question is also relevant when deploying **"proprietary"** algorithms to the cloud.  How is that get addressed?

Thank you for any insights!

Comment: Thank you Mike! The link you suggested helps to confirm my understanding that it is almost impossible to protect python source code. It is still not clear how to achieve at least some level of protection on Linux-based systems. py2exe seems to work only on windows.

Comment: OT: The company I work for deploys all our application as proprietary, but with full source. We offer 24/7 support for our software. So even if someone at the customer company is going to "steal" the sources, what can they possibly do with it? Look at some fancy formulas? The real value comes from constantly improving the code and offering support and writing customer specific extensions. And legally we're still the copyright holder, so the "thief" would be in big trouble if he'd actually were to make a business out of stolen code and our lawyers found out.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, theoretically hosting anywhere besides a host you own completely is not safe. However, if you're going with any major hosting service I can assure you two things:

1. There are numerous systems in place to make your code not accessible
2. No one is going to steal your code.

However, if you are that concerned, look in to Python "freezing" tools like PyInstaller or PyFreeze, however these are *still* completely able to be deobfuscated.